# Quick way to redefine groups for tables?

Tags: r, grouping

Sadly I'm not well versed in either `data.table` and `dplyr` (or whatever package could help here), and an online search as well as looking into the documentation of both packages did not answer my question.

I often need to `table()` two variables, and almost as often the pre-defined categories of the variables need to be changed for grouping purposes. I really think there ought to be a quick way to do this, but I can't figure out how.

Some example data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("male", 
                    "female"), class = "factor"), company = structure(c(3L, 5L, 3L, 
                    2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
                    1L), .Label = c("Company1", "Company2", "Company3", "Company4", "Company5"
                    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sex", "company"), row.names = c(11993L, 
                    21167L, 9263L, 6086L, 18854L, 15157L, 4805L, 13789L, 17777L, 18820L, 
                    9810L, 10167L, 6968L, 5769L, 7961L, 12034L, 18046L, 7858L, 22404L, 22647L), 
                    class = "data.frame")
```

Now suppose I need the gender distribution of the companies. A quick `table(mydata$sex, mydata$company)` would result in

```
       Company1 Company2 Company3 Company4 Company5
  male          1        1        3        2        1
  female        0        3        4        1        4
```

But what if I need to get the gender distribution of `Company1` in comparison to the combined distribution of `Company2`, `Company3` and `Company4`, while disregarding `Company5` entirely?

The table as it should be:

```
        Company1 Company234 
  male          1        6
  female        0        8
```

The awkward approach would be to either redefine the `Company`-variable or create a new variable with the correct grouping and setting `Company5` to `NA`.

I would like an approach with which I would not need to define a new variable, and instead could temporarily redefine the groups within the `table`-call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a new variable already only involves two lines of code plus the `table` statement itself:

```
co <- mydata$company
levels(co) <- c("co1", "co234", "co234", "co234", NA)

with(mydata, table(sex, co))
```

giving:

```
        co
sex      co1 co234
  male     1     6
  female   0     8
```

or in one line:

```
with(mydata, table(sex, co = `levels<-`(company, c("co1", "co234", "co234", "co234", NA))))
```

Comment: Huh, guess I worded my question wrong :-/ I know how to do this, I'm looking for a way to get my table without having to create a new variable.

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! I guess this is base R? I didn't know you could express it like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to comment on your first line, it wasn't really about needing less lines than about being able to do the regrouping temporarily without having to clutter my data with new variables, which I won't need outside of the tables. That's why I like that one-liner, it does exactly what I wanted.